# Cannot instantiate abstract class ... in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, apc

I have just installed yesterday ***apc*** and I am now getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class
ACME\WebBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder in
/var/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 743
```

and in that line there is:

```
protected function getEposMain_MenuBuilderService()
{
    return $this->services['epos_main.menu_builder'] = new \ACME\WebBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder($this->get('knp_menu.factory'));
}
```

Does any one know what does it mean and what I can do with it?

services.yml

```
services:
    epos_main.menu_builder:
        class: ACME\WebBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]

    epos_main.menu.main:
        class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem # the service definition requires setting the class
        factory_service: epos_main.menu_builder
        factory_method: createMainMenu
        arguments:
            - @request
            - @twig
            - 'ACMEWebBundle:Menu:menu.html.twig'
        scope: request # needed as we have the request as a dependency here
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main } # The alias is what is used to retrieve the menu

    epos.twig.epos_extension:
        class: ACME\WebBundle\Twig\ePOSTwigExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

a bit of MenuBuilder Class code:

```
namespace ACME\WebBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MenuBuilder
{
    private $factory;

    /**
     * @param FactoryInterface $factory
     */
    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function createMainMenu(Request $request)
    {

        $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
        $menu->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'nav');
        ...
        ...
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache?

Comment: Check your `services.yml` It looks like you declared your service as non abstract whilst it is. Did you forget to add a factory ?

Comment: The problem is this that everything was working fine and I haven't change anything in that services.yml and in that class. I have edited my question with adding code from services.yml and a bit code of a MenuBuilder class.

Answer (score 12):

Well the error is pretty self-explanatory. You cannot **instantiate** an Abstract Class as per OOP rules !

Your `MenuBuilder` is an **`abstract`** class and you are trying to instantiate with a **`new`** keyword which is not possible.

Comment: How can you tell if a class is abstract? he did not declare it abstract in its definition... I am currently stuck in a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your MenuBuilder class was abstract at some point and you changed it to be a concrete class, it's possible that APC still has the old version lurking around (in memory).

Try restarting your webserver.