# Abstract base class cannot access private members of derived class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class Entity. And i have a class Person which inherits the Entity Class. But my class Entity is not able to access private members of class Person. How do i make it do it?

```
<?php
abstract class Entity
{
    public function view()
    {
        echo $name; //Fatal Error. Can't Access
    }
}
class Person extends Entity
{
    private $name;
}
```

Comment: What if I extend `Entity` with another class named `Desk` that does *not* have a name?

Comment: The variable name $name is dynamic. The function view() is called from the derived class with some arguments. And those arguments are actually variables which are defined in the derived class. So this can never go wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735149/cannot-instantiate-abstract-class-in-appdevdebugprojectcontainer-php-symfo

Comment: @RobertRozas: I am not trying to instantiate the abstract class.

Comment: why does private (why private?) property that the base class is already AWARE OF is declared somewhere else, shouldn't the abstract class give the rules e.g. properties that can be overriden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$name` is `private`, so is only available in the `Person` class. Try making it `protected`. And then from the `Entity` class, access it with `static::$name;`

Notice the use of the `static` keyword. This is an example of late static binding. In simple terms, it means use the value which belongs to the derived child.

Bare in mind, depending on the objects your are modelling, it may make more sense to put the `$name` property in `Entity`, so that all other child classes also have the property, instead of redeclaring it each time. You would then access it in your child classes with `$this->name;`

Comment: I've made a new architecture for my classes. This one didn't seem right. :)

Comment: Great. Good luck with your project.